# What does it mean for $(t,x(t))$ to leave a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

In the Theorem of Maximal Interval of Existence which states that;

> An $\sf IVP$ has a maximal interval of existence, and it is of the form $(t^−,t^+)$, with $t^  −\in [−\infty,+\infty)$ and $t^+\in(−\infty,+\infty]$. There is a unique solution $x(t)$ on $(t^−,t^+)$, and $(t,x(t))$ leaves every compact subset $K$ of $D$ as $t\downarrow t^−$ and as $t\uparrow t^+$.

"There is a unique solution $x(t)$ on $(t^-,t^+)$ and **$(t,x(t))$ leaves every compact subset $K$ of $D$**" Im not too clear on the bolded text. I will be glad if someone can kindly explain it to me.

Thanks

Comment: You should give the whole theorem statement.

Comment: An IVP has a maximal interval of existence, and it is of the form (t−,t+), with t−∈[−∞,∞) and t+∈(−∞,∞]. There is a unique solution x(t) on (t−,t+), and (t,x(t)) leaves every compact subset K of D as t↓t− and as t↑t+.

Comment: @Clifrichie Without more context and without knowing what I'm talking about, I'd guess it means that given a compact subset $K$ of $D$, there exists $t_0\in (t^-, t^+)$ such that $(t,x(t))\not \in K$.

Comment: @Clifrichie The theorem should be added to the question instead of being a comment. The theorem doesn't mention wthat $D$ is.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you. Sorry for not being too clear. I just posted the whole theorem statement as suggested by Chris.

Comment: So the theorem statement just uses the letter $D$ without explaining what it means?

Comment: yes...This is a link to the theorem statement that I found on a thread here if you dont mind http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299005/how-do-you-find-the-maximal-interval-of-existence-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: Looks like the actual statement is on page 15 of http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/theoryofodes2008.pdf, if anyone feels like editing it into the question.

Comment: I think D is an open set of R x R^d

Comment: @ChrisEagle I think the statements are the same now. I edited it into the question

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\{(t, x(t)):t_{-} < t < t_{+} \}$. If the trajectory leaves every compact set $K \subset R^2$, then we can interpret this as $T \cap K^c \neq \emptyset$ for all $K$.

Suppose $D = R^2$. Taking $K=\overline{B_R(0)}$ implies that our trajectory is unbounded.

Okay, now suppose $D$ is some arbitrary bounded open set in $R^2$. If $K\subset D$, then we must have $dist(D^c, K) > \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$.  If $T\cap K^c \neq \emptyset$, we interpret it as the trajectory approaching the boundary arbitrarily close.

In essence, these two cases highlight then that theorem then tells us for any open set $D$, either the trajectory will approach the boundary or it will go to infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much.@nayrb