# What does being maximal (non-continuable) say about a solution of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

What does being maximal (non-continuable) say about a solution of a differential equation?

Do I understand it correctly that a solution of a differential equation can be called maximal if it is unique (so its domain is defined in such a way that there is only one unique solution on it)?
What can we infer from knowing that a solution of a differential equation is maximal?

The question has been motivated by the following problem:

How many zeros does the maximal solution of the following initial value problem have on its domain?

$$y' = \frac{y}{\cos x}$$

$$y(0) = 2$$

The solution to this IVP that I've got: $y = 2(\sec x + \tan x)$

Comment: The solution is defined and unique on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ which is the maximal interval of existence. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298974/solution-of-first-order-differential-equation-and-maximal-interval).

Comment: "a solution can be called maximal if it is unique" No this is not what being maximal means, please check your notes.

Comment: What does maximal mean?